# Quiero hacer un conversor de unidades sin jquery

Tags: javascript, html

me gustaría hacer un conversor de unidades de longitud, masa etc, por ejemplo pasar de kilometros a metros y asi... pero no quiero hacer todas las conbinaciones posibles de todo... ya que hay cientos, por lo tanto me preguntaba como podria hacerlo de una forma más sencilla.

```
<input type="text" id="deLongitud">
<select name="medidaLongitud" id="longitudInicio" class="selector">
    <option value="seleccionaOpcion">Seleciona una opcion</option>
    <option value="kilometros">Kilometros</option>
    <option value="hectometros">Hectometros</option>
    <option value="decametros">Decametros</option>
    <option value="metros">Metros</option>
    <option value="decimetros">Decimetros</option>
    <option value="centimetros">Centimetros</option>
    <option value="milimetros">Milimetros</option>
</select>
<select name="medidaLongitud" id="longitudFin" class="selector">
    <option value="seleccionaOpcion">Seleciona una opcion</option>
    <option value="kilometros2">Kilometros</option>
    <option value="hectometros2">Hectometros</option>
    <option value="decametros2">Decametros</option>
    <option value="metros2">Metros</option>
    <option value="decimetros2">Decimetros</option>
    <option value="centimetros2">Centimetros</option>
    <option value="milimetros2">Milimetros</option>
</select>
```

Esto es lo que recoge los datos... entonces quiero que al seleccionar en el primer select kilometros por ejemplo, en el segundo select metros y en el input poner por ejemplo 10, al presionar un boton llamado Solucion:

```
<button class="solution">Solucion</button>
```

Me devuelva en un span la solucion

```
<span class="result"></span>
```

No se si me he explicado bien la verdad

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Si te has explicado bien, pero no has mostrado el código relevante de lo que has intentado. Puedes leer [mcve] para que tengas una idea. ¿Ya tienes las fórmulas de las conversiones? ¿Ya tienes las variables donde vas a capturar los valores? Muestra lo que hayas intentado y el error o problema que tienes, no lo haremos por ti. Saludos

Comment: Tengo las formulas claro... lo que yo quiero no es que me lo digais, yo lo que quiero saber es si hay alguna forma de hacer los calculos sin necesidad de poner un if con las 336 combinaciones disponibles (he calculado cuantas combinaciones son), y de ser asi si me podriais decir como se haria...

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podría servir lo siguiente: Puedes asignarle el valor de cada unidad de medida, creo que de eso no te podrás escapar, después dependiendo de los valores que escogió el usuario y dependiendo cual quieras convertir a cual, puedes pasar el valor a convertir a la unidad mas estandar (en el caso de querer convertir kilómetros a centímetros puedes convertir primero el valor a metros y después a centímetros) ejemplo: 100 kilometros a metros = 100 * 1000 = 100,000 metros.

100,000 metros a centimetros es 100,000 * 100 = 10,000,000.

Entonces 10,000,000 de centimetros equivalen a 100 kilometros.
Eso funcionaria para cuando estas convirtiendo unidades grandes a pequeñas, si fuera el caso contrario entonces seria la operacion contraria que es la division, por lo cual debes determinar si el numero que quieres convertir a otra unidad es mas grande o mas pequeño que la otra unidad, todo eso se puede hacer en una funcion para que cuando le pases los parametros lo haga todo automaticamente.

Si te da pereza igual puedes decirle al usuario que el ponga cuanto cale cada unidad de medida, aunque no te lo recomiendo, eso es trabajo de programador, lo que si puedes hacer es dar la opcion de que pueda añadir unidades de medida personalizadas (eso te podría servir por si alguien quiere calcular alguna moneda virtual o algo asi).

Igual te aconsejo lo del comentario de arriba, tampoco es tan difícil, y si estudias o estas en la universidad seguramente te habrá tocado convertir binario a hexadecimal o algo asi, son exactamente los mismos pasos, igual se puede hacer de una manera mas corta pero debes de buscar como.